# Is this function defined in this domain continuous at $x = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

$f$, a function defined on $(-1,1)$, satisfying $|f(x)|\leq \sqrt \mid{x}$

How can I tell if this is continuous at $x = 0$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{|x|}$ (`\sqrt{|x|}`, the `\mid` command is for the "divides" symbol)? Also, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? What's stopping you?

Comment: Consider the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \sqrt{\vert x \vert}=0$, you have $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \vert f(x) \vert =0$ according to the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem?wprov=sfti1). Therefore $f$ is continuous at zero.